# Connect an access database to a pandas dataframe but I facing a IM004 error

Tags: pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

```
#access database
db_file = r'C:\\Users\\yoeri.samwel\\Documents\\DSV_data_cleaning\\Database2.accdb'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={};'.format(db_file))

query = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
dataf = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

running this code throws me this error:
`pyodbc.Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Not sure what to fix this? Can someone help? I tried reinstalling the Access 2010 engine but this did not help.